# How do I solve this property declaration error that typescript keeps complaining to me?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a piece of code in my componentDidMount lifecycle function that does the following

```
this.unsubscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: RNFirebase.User) => {
   this.setState({ user });
});
```

`onAuthStateChanged` returns an unsubscriber function that needs to be called when the component unmounts. The problem is that if I declare the unsubscriber variable like so

```
constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.unsubscriber: Function = null
}
```

typescript complains by saying that the property "unsubscriber" does not exist(also that I cannot assign to function because it is a constant or read only property). I tried doing other stuff like passing it as a state like so.

```
type AppState = {
  user: RNFirebase.User | null;
  unsubscriber: Function | null;
}

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
   ....
}
```

but that didn't do me any good; got the same error when I try to assign the return value from `onAuthStateChanged`. `this.unsubscriber = null` would work just fine if I was just doing react without typescript but I'm trying to use both.

The closest I got was this

```
type AppState = {
  user: RNFirebase.User | null;
};

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  private unsubscriber: Function;
  ....
}
```

But the error I got for this one is that it not initialized there or in the constructor and I can't assign null to it. So what can I do?

Here is the entire code that I'm working with.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { auth, RNFirebase } from 'react-native-firebase';
import { Login } from './screens';

type AppState = {
  user: RNFirebase.User | null;
};

class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  private unsubscriber: Function; // This has to be initialized.

  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user: RNFirebase.User) => {
      this.setState({ user });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.unsubscriber) {
      this.unsubscriber();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;

    if (!user) {
      return <Login />;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to my awesome app {user.email}!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to keep your `unsubscriber` declaration as a class member but make it optional ([optional class properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#optional-class-properties)). Also, `Function` type is generally not useful at all (just take a look at what is the interface that it defines) and you're better off defining its type as `() => void` if its return value is going to be ignored (see [callback types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#callback-types)). So, try something like this:

```
private unsubscriber?: () => void;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize `unsubscriber` property:

```
private unsubscriber: (() => void) | null = null;
```